# COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context

Tags: docker

I have a monorepo that has holds various Go services and libraries. The directory structure is like the following:

```
monorepo
 services 
  service-a 
   - Dockerfile
go.mod
go.sum
```

This `go.mod` file resides in the root of the `monorepo` directory and the services use the dependencies stated in that file.

I build the Docker image with this command:

```
docker build -t some:tag ./services/service-a/
```

When I try to build my Docker image from the root of `monorepo` directory with the above docker command I get the following error:

> COPY failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../../go.mod ()

Below is my Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.14.1-alpine3.11

RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates git

# Enable Go Modules
ENV GO111MODULE=on

# Set the Current Working Directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy go mod and sum files
COPY ../../go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o service-a

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/service-a"]
```

Is there something I have to do to be able to add files into my Docker image that aren't in the current directory without having to have a separate go.mod and go.sum in each service within the monorepo?

Comment: how did you solve your problem? I have exactly the same structure in my java project

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Docker only allows adding files to the image from the context, which is by default the directory containing the Dockerfile. You can specify a different context when you build, but again, it won't let you include files outside that context:

```
docker build -f ./services/service-a/Dockerfile .
```

This should use the current directory as the context.

Alternatively, you can create a temp directory, copy all the artifacts there and use that as the build context. This can be automated by a makefile or build script.

Answer (score 8):

You can build and manage your docker containers using `docker-compose`, then this problem can be solved with the help `context` directive, for example:

```
project_folder  
├─── src  
│    └── folder1
│        └── folder2
│            └── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yaml   
└── copied_file.ext
```

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3'
services:

    your_service_name:
        build:
            context: ./ #project_folder for this case
            dockerfile: ./src/folder1/folder2/Dockefile
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM xxx
COPY copied_file.ext /target_folder/
```

build or rebuild services:

```
docker-compose build
```

run a one-off command on a service:

```
docker-compose run your_service_name <command> [arguments]
```